# Splitting ID based on values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a large data.frame with p columns and n rows.
I would like to change the ID, i.e. split the frame if the value 1 is obtained. However for each ID the value may be present multiple times, therefore it becomes tricky.
I was thinking about making a order, so everytime a df$Value==1 then the row should have df$order==1(next,2... until a df$value==1 again)

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(ID= c(rep(1,3), rep(2,7), rep(3,5)),
             Value= c(0,0,1,
                      0,0,1,0,1,1,0,
                      0,0,1,0,1))

# Desired result
df <- data.frame(ID= c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(2.1,2), rep(2.2,1),rep(2.3,1), rep(3,3), rep(3.1,2)),
             Value= c(0,0,1,
                      0,0,1,
                      0,1,
                      1,
                      0,
                      0,0,1,
                      0,1))

# Alternative desired result
df <- data.frame(ID= c(rep(2,3), rep(2.1,2), rep(2.2,1),rep(2.3,1), rep(3,3), rep(3.1,2)),
             Value= c(0,0,1,
                      0,1,
                      1,
                      0,
                      0,0,1,
                      0,1))
```

I have tried to do this:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Order= seq(from=Value[1], to=which(Value==1), by=1))
```

But it doesnt really give me what I want.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ID := seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)[shift(cumsum(Value==1), fill=0)+1] + ID, ID]
```

---

Or the same with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ID1 = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)[lag(cumsum(Value==1), default=0)+1] + ID) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(ID = ID1) %>%
  select(-ID1)
# A tibble: 15 × 2
#      ID Value
#   <dbl> <dbl>
#1    1.0     0
#2    1.0     0
#3    1.0     1
#4    2.0     0
#5    2.0     0
#6    2.0     1
#7    2.1     0
#8    2.1     1
#9    2.2     1
#10   2.3     0
#11   3.0     0
#12   3.0     0
#13   3.0     1
#14   3.1     0
#15   3.1     1
```

Comment: Im not very confident in data.table. But I understand the dplyr solution, very smart way of doing it. Thanks!